# underscore js template does not work

Tags: templates, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

this should be easy or simple,
but I donot know why it doesnot work. I waste here about 1 whole day.

https://jsfiddle.net/panyongfeng/m73vnz9j/

```
<script>
        var tpl = "hello: <%= name %>";
        var compiled = _.template(tpl);
        compiled({
            name: "dadf"
        });
        alert(compiled());
</script>
```

I just get "hello result", which should be hello dadf.
Would you please point out what's wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the examples in the documentation. When they say this:

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
=> "hello: moe"
```

The context is that they're working inside a REPL as though they ran `node` from the command line. That means that the stuff after `=>` is the result of the last expression and the `hello: moe` string is what `compiled({name: 'moe'})` returns. Running the template function returns the filled in template as a string, it doesn't stash the results anywhere.

You want to drop the last `alert` call in favor of this:

```
alert(compiled({ name: "dadf" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but if you want to use the result then you need to store the result of compiled method. So your code should be -

```
var dump = compiled({ name: "dadf" });
alert(dump);
```